# Turning an npm package into an npm organization

Tags: npm

I have an npm package `my-package` and would like to turn it into an organisation, since I want the package to be actually made up of several smaller packages.

I looked and looked, and couldn't find a way to do this. I am surprised nobody else wants to do it.

I thought about deleting the current package and create an organisation. However, there is no way to "delete" an NPM package -- only mark it as deprecated. If I do mark it as deprecated, I am not sure I will be able to then register an org with the same name (will I?)

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning a NPM package into an NPM organization is like turning a grilled cheese sandwich into the house of parliament. They are fundamentally different concepts.

You can create an organization with the same name though without deleting your package, and you can re-publish your package inside this organization by giving it a new name.

After all that, you can mark your old package with the old name as 'deprecated'.

I did the same thing, and that's why there's now 2 packages:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/curveball
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@curveball/core

Comment: "Turning a NPM package into an NPM organization is like turning a grilled cheese sandwich into the house of parliament." <-- Best. Comment. Ever. :D